# why does my KMPlayer play no sound for second audio stream?

Tags: audio, kmplayer

i am playing a mkv movie on KMPlayer when i switch to another audio stream no sound is being played and i am sure that there is nothing wrong with the second audio stream of the movie.

i tried to uncheck AC3 and DTS under Internal Audio decoder in preference but it did not work.
i also tried to  change matroska splitter to gabset MKV splitter .that did not work either.

what should i do?

Comment: What does KMPlayer say about the file's streams? This will state what formats the audio streams are in and this would might make it clear that the problem is simply that you are missing a codec.

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was (right click on Kmplayer) "Main Controls" -> "Audio" -> "Audio Renderer" and set it to "Default Device". I had headphones selected as the device to be used and it only played audio for the first instance and the rest had no sound, but when I set 'Audio Renderer' to 'default device' I had audio for multiple instances again.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and fixed it by adding K-Lite code packs all **LAV decoders** to KMPlayer ***custom filter manager*** (using kmplayer `prefences -> custom filter manager -> add registered filter`) and then switching from `KMP Copy Transform Stream Switcher` to `Gabests Stream Switcher` (prefences -> **Multi-Audio Streams**).

KMPlayer plays other audio files after its next run. (**Restart KMPlayer**.)

Answer (score 0):

### Follow these steps in KMPlayer:

Options > Playback > Output > **Audio Renderer** > *1: system default*

---

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be outdated audio drivers. I suggest you download the latest ones from the manufacturers website.